# unison-fsmonitor doesn't detect any changes

Tags: linux, synchronization, unison

I've just compiled unison 2.48.4 for my own. It works perfectly after normal call but `unison-fsmonitor` doesn't deect any filesystem changes and doesn't synchronize anything. Filesystem is EXT4.
`-debug all/verbose` doesn't bring any log. The only thing it puts on the terminal is `VERSION 1`, after hitting any key it terminates with message: `ERROR unknown%20command%20''`
No mater whether invoked with sudo or as regular user.
Nothing in ~/.unison/unison.log
Any ideas about the possible reasons? Any ideas how to debug it?

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me how you compiled it? What version of `lablgtk` did you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The executable `unison-fsmonitor` is not meant to be run on its own, but is instead just a tool that Unison uses to watch your filesystem. To have Unison watch your filesystem for changes just run `unison` with the line `repeat=watch` in your profile, or from the command line run

```
unison -repeat watch
```

Comment: Hi, not sure if I should open a new question, but I also compiled my own 2.48.4 and the `repeat=watch` works fine in the CLI version, but the GUI version does not automatically detect and push changes, I have to manually scan and push them. Is that how it is supposed to be? Thanks.

Comment: @Michael I don't think that's how it's supposed to be, but I have no experience with the GUI version. You should ask a new question.